# Store function name with attributes in hash table

Tags: c++

Suppose, I have the following program:

```
__attribute__((annotate("ex"))) void ex() {};
void val() {};

__attribute__((annotate("foo"))) void foo() {
 ex();
cout<<"You have called a function with an attribute"<<endl;
val();
cerr<<"Error!You have called a function without an attribute"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
foo();
return 0;
}
```

If you observe, main() calls foo() and foo() in turn calls ex() and val().When ex() is called there is no problem as it has an attribute associated with it but whereas when it calls val(), it should display error message stating that this function has not got any attribute.

So, for this I need to keep track of functions which has attributes and without attributes in the hash table and check it whenever a function is called.

And, I have no clue how to do this?I hope now its clear.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  The compiler should tell you if you redeclare a function.

Comment: @NathanOliver:I am working on compilers that's the reason

Comment: Read about [Symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) and implement one.

Comment: @Shreevardhan.I am just new to all this.Thank you for answering

Comment: You might want to look at how GLEW works. That's a much more advanced case of this kind of "is X function here" business.

Comment: Pavikirhi:  I think I understand your question, but it is not clear, that may be why you have gotten so many down votes.

Please explain clearly what you'd like accomplished, otherwise, as stated your question is "NO: C++ does not have introspection, from the code you don't know what the identifiers (names of functions, for example) are.  However, you can capture the overload of a function and its arguments into a *binding*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are going to need to use *structures* or *classes*.

I'll give you my take on a parameter and you can expand to a function.

A function parameter has a *name* and a *type*:

```
struct Function_Parameter
{
  std::string name;
  std::string type;
};
```

A function also *has-a* name and a *return* type:

```
struct Function_Token
{
  std::string name;
  std::string return_type;
};
```

A function can have zero or more parameters.  Thus usually means a container of some sort.  So, use a `std::vector`:

```
struct Function_Token
{
  std::string name;
  std::string return_type;
  std::vector<Function_Parameter> parameters;
};
```

Many compilers may convert names into numeric values (using some kind of hash function or table).  This usually speeds up compilations because strings take a long time to compare.